# Python: Given a float, return number of decimals

Tags: python, string

examples:

0.28
-->  2

0.1234
-->  4

0.01345000
--> 5

My answer:

```
len(str(k)[str(k).index('.')+1:])
```

It works but it is also super ugly.  Anything more pythonic?

Comment: I would be very careful about floats and any guarantee of number of decimals, e.g. `str(0.1+0.2) == '0.30000000000000004'` you might have expected only `1` but your function returns `17`. Use [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html?highlight=decimal#decimal-objects) if you want any certainty.

Comment: for completeness, in order to first drop the zeros on the right side of the decimal object, we must use the normalize() method first.